# How to reduce audio playback speed in NAudio?

Tags: c#, mp3, naudio, directsound

My code to play mp3 file looks like this:

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
Mp3FileReader fread = new Mp3FileReader(stream);
IWavePlayer audioPlayer = new DirectSoundOut();
audioPlayer.Init(fread);
audioPlayer.Play();
```

Now, I want to play mp3 file with reduced speed (half normal speed).

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

NAudio does not include a ready-made component to change the speed of audio playback. However, it is possible if you create your own derived WaveStream / IWaveProvider and implement a speedup algorithm yourself.